# Prevention of client side aws client credentials and CMK exposure

Tags: java, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

1. I encrypted some data on server-side with a CMK of AWS KMS. So an encrypted data key is created, and cyphertext blob  will be send to client-side
2. On client-side, for decryption, I need to provide aws access key and secret key and CMK to implement the decrypt method.

My question is : How do we securely store this key without exposing the keys to the client-side?